# Mysql order by field gives incorrect order

Tags: mysql

provider_id could be 1,2,3

```
SELECT * FROM `news` order by field (provider_id, 1,3)
```

I expect it show first records with the provider_id = 1 then 3 and after them with the provider_id = 2

In real it shows first all the records with the provider_id =2 and only then 1, 3

How to write correct query when i want list firstly only 1 and 3 and after them all the rest provider_id's?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you expect that?

`FIELD` returns the index in the list that matches the value of the first argument, and 0 if it's not found, so your `ORDER BY` will obviously sort rows with `provider_id` not 1 or 3 first.

To test it, just try adding a column with the value of `field (provider_id, 1,3)`, you'll see for yourself:

```
SELECT *,field (provider_id, 1,3) FROM `news` order by field (provider_id, 1,3)
```

You could simply add `DESC` (and possibly swap 1 and 3 if you want provider_id=1 first):

```
SELECT * FROM `news` order by field (provider_id, 3, 1) DESC
```